MACHINE LEARNING : numpy , issue dealing with NaN values
ISSUE: Dealing with Nan values
I have tried replacing the Nan values with 0 to test if it would output anything. However , even with zeros filling the Nan slots the MSE returns Nan which makes me think there's an issue with the predicting that the Matrix Factorization class is supposed to handle. Furthermore I'm not supposed to modify them to zeros since It will affect the rating
Initially I am taking the user and movie data from a file, here is the head:
movie_inds  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     ...    
user_inds                                                               ...  
0            3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...  
1            NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...  
2            NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN   4.0   NaN  ...  
3            NaN   NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN   4.0   4.0  ...  
4            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...

movie_inds  1672  1673  1674  1675  1676  1677  1678  1679  1680  1681  
user_inds  
0            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
1            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
2            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
3            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
4            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

\[5 rows x 1682 columns\]

The NaN values are expected since users havent rated all movies.
Then I am using Matrix Factorization to convert the array and deal with the Nan values by predicting:
\`# MatrixFactorization class
class MatrixFactorization():
\# constructor
def __init__(self, rating_matrix, rating_matrix_val, k=5, lmbda=0.01, max_epochs=50, lr=0.1):
'''
rating_matrix: the matrix of rating (row: user, col: movie)
k : int, default=2
Number of latent features
lmbda : float, default=0.01
Regularization parameter
max_epochs : int, default=15
Max number of iterations to run
lr: float, default:0.1
Learning rate
'''
self.rating_matrix = rating_matrix
self.rating_matrix_val = rating_matrix_val
self.k = k
self.lmbda = lmbda
self.max_epochs = max_epochs
self.lr = lr
self.U = np.random.normal(scale=1./self.k, size=(rating_matrix.shape\[0\], self.k))
self.V = np.random.normal(scale=1./self.k, size=(self.k, rating_matrix.shape\[1\]))
self.b_u = np.zeros(rating_matrix.shape\[0\])
self.b_i = np.zeros(rating_matrix.shape\[1\])
self.b = np.mean(rating_matrix\[np.where(rating_matrix != 0)\])
self.mean_squared_errors = \[\]
self.mean_squared_errors_val = \[\]

    # fitting the model
    def fit(self):
        for it in range(self.max_epochs):
            for i in range(len(self.rating_matrix)):
                for j in range(len(self.rating_matrix[i])):
                    if self.rating_matrix[i][j] > 0:
                        eij = self.rating_matrix[i][j] - (self.predict_rating_user_movie(i, j))
                        self.b_u[i] += self.lr * (eij - self.lmbda * self.b_u[i])
                        self.b_i[j] += self.lr * (eij - self.lmbda * self.b_i[j])
                        self.U[i,:] += self.lr * (eij * self.V[:,j] - self.lmbda * self.U[i,:])
                        self.V[:,j] += self.lr * (eij * self.U[i,:] - self.lmbda * self.V[:,j])
    
            self.mean_squared_errors.append(self.mse_training(self.rating_matrix, self.predict()))
            self.mean_squared_errors_val.append(self.mse_validation(self.rating_matrix, self.rating_matrix_val, self.predict()))
    
    # reporting model's mse using the training set
    def mse_training(self, true_rating, pred_rating):
        '''
        pred_matrix: the predict matrix of rating (row: user, col: movie)
        return: mean squared error
        '''
        error = 0
        for rt, rp in zip(true_rating, pred_rating):
            for vt, vp in zip(rt, rp):
                if vt > 0:
                    error += pow(vt - vp, 2)
        return np.sqrt(error)
    
    # reporting model's mse using testing set
    def mse_validation(self, true_rating, test_rating, pred_rating):
        '''
        pred_matrix: the predict matrix of rating (row: user, col: movie)
        return: mean squared error
        '''
        error = 0
        for rt, rtt, rp in zip(true_rating, test_rating, pred_rating):
            for vt, vtt, vp in zip(rt, rtt, rp):
                if vt == -1:
                    error += pow(vtt - vp, 2)
        return np.sqrt(error)
    
    # predicting the user's movie rating
    def predict_rating_user_movie(self, i, j):
        '''
        i: user row
        j: movie col
        '''
        return self.b + self.b_u[i] + self.b_i[j] + np.dot(self.U[i,:],self.V[:,j])
    
    # rating prediction
    def predict(self):
        '''
        return: rating prediction
        '''
        return self.b + self.b_u[:,np.newaxis] + self.b_i[np.newaxis:, ] + np.dot(self.U, self.V)
    
    # plotting model's loss
    def plot_loss(self):
        iters = [i for i in range(self.max_epochs)]
        plt.xlabel("Iterations")
        plt.ylabel("Mean Squared Error")
        plt.plot(iters, self.mean_squared_errors)
        plt.plot(iters, self.mean_squared_errors_val)
    
    # mean square error result
    def mse_result(self):
        return self.mean_squared_errors[-1]

\`

The issue I am having is in this part of the code , I am getting Nan for the MSE as well as the Nan aren't being handled by my matrix factorization class
# grid search function implementation
def grid_search(parameters):
    best_mse = 1000 # choose the maximum mse initially
    best_params = None  # initialize best parameters as None

    # loop over all parameters that are passed through the grid_search function
    for params in parameters:
        k, lmbda, max_epochs, lr = params  # unpack the parameters

        # make your model with all the parameters
        mf_model = MatrixFactorization(rating_matrix_training, rating_matrix_test, k=k, lmbda=lmbda, max_epochs=max_epochs, lr=lr)

        # fit model
        mf_model.fit()

        # predict labels
        pred_ratings = mf_model.predict()

        # measure training mse
        mse_train = mf_model.mse_training(rating_matrix_training, pred_ratings)

        # measure validation mse
        mse_val = mf_model.mse_validation(rating_matrix_training, rating_matrix_test, pred_ratings)

        # find the best parameters with the minimum validation mse and update best_params
        if mse_val < best_mse:
            best_mse = mse_val
            best_params = params

        print("Parameters:", params, "Training MSE:", mse_train, "Validation MSE:", mse_val)

    # print the minimum mse
    print("Minimum Validation MSE:", best_mse)

    # return the best parameters
    return best_params

HYPERPARAMETER TUNING:
  import itertools

# input your parameters
k = (5, 10, 20)
lmbda = (0.01, 0.1)
e = (20, 50)
lr = (0.001, 0.01, 0.5)

# merge all parameters in one list
parameters= [k,lmbda,e,lr]
parameters= list(itertools.product(*parameters))

# run the grid search
best_params = grid_search(parameters)


please use a minimum reproducible example. There's too much going on over here. From a cursory look though, the following is my assessment
NaN need to be handled appropriately. Operations with NaN will produce NaN. This is not a problem with lumpy. for instance, NaN + 1 = NaN.
I would recommend a placeholder for NaN so that the algorithm can identify and assign appropirate scores to those elements where NaNs occur.

hello @climate-coder , thanks for the comment. But shouldnt The matrix Factorization function deal with the Nan values? It has a predict(self) method that is suppsoed to do that. Furthermore, adding a placeholder that is a number could be an issue since it has to do with movies rating

again, any operation which encounters a NaN, will spit out NaN. For instance,
eij = self.rating_matrix[i][j] - (self.predict_rating_user_movie(i, j)
The abovee uses rating matrix, there is no code that confirms where the training rating matrix comes from. Hence, the need to provide a minimum reproducible example. from your long code I would imagine is the first dataframe you shared. Anyway, the line of code will end up giving a NaN as an output because it encounters an NaN. None values can't be handled this way. If it is a rating matrix, you need to provide rating to all columns.

I understand that any operation using Nan values is going to return a Nan value. For example I've modified the array to change all Nan values to zeros. When running the grid search I am getting this warning:
`RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
self.V[:,j] += self.lr * (eij * self.U[i,:] - self.lmbda * self.V[:,j])
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar power
error += pow(vt - vp, 2)`
As well as this Output:
Parameters: (5, 0.01, 20, 0.1) Training MSE: nan Validation MSE: nan

That's not an issue. You're technically using 0 as a placeholder. So shouldn't be a problem. Because the computation is now going ahead, the warning only tells you that the datatype you defined or in your case did not define fails to capture the result. You initialised your array with integer datatype but then end up manipulating the results into floats. Technically, Python converts types on the fly but because this is an array with a set dtype, you encounter this warning. you can simply change the dtype to float64 for this warning to go away. The warning has nothing to do with your problem.

Ignoring the RuntimeWarning , what could be causing the MSE for both validation and training to return Nan?

I can't say until I runt this on my machine and debug. You're obviously still encountering an NaN somewhere or performing an unallowed operation. It is not immediately clear from the code. Use your IDEs debugger to step into the function line by line for one epoch and identify the source. This is very easy to do with Spyder.

I kept the Grid Search running and got a few MSE that were as good outputs:
Parameters: (5, 0.01, 20, 0.01) Training MSE: 232.7624099592626 Validation MSE: 132.4585045999102 Parameters: (5, 0.01, 20, 0.5) Training MSE: nan Validation MSE: nan Parameters: (5, 0.01, 50, 0.1) Training MSE: nan Validation MSE: nan 
Could it be that some of the hyperparameters such a lr , is a bit too high cause this? I noticed it the MSE is computed when lr = 0.01

Might be. Another theory that comes to mind is that of vanishing gradients. Your gradient descent might produce results so small the division with them is leading to NaN. you'll have to debug this thoroughly yourself.

I was able to make it work with a specific lr of anything less than 0.1 . Thanks For the Help! @climate-coder
